# Wrong scanning in C

Tags: c, scanf

My university task is to write a small program, that will calculate quadratic equation, that user enter in this format: ax^2+bx+c=0(for example 3x^2+2x-3=0) . My program have to scan a, b and c and calculate roots of equation. I wrote this to scan coefficients:

```
scanf("%fx^2+%fx+%f=0", &a, &b, &c);
```

And its work for equations like this: 2x^2+2x+3=0. But when i have equation with "-" in it(for example 1x^2+1x-2=0) scanning doesnt work correctly. It scan 1 and 1 true, but instead of -2 it scan wrong really big number. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Fyi, It doesn't "scan wrong really big number". Taking the time to actually check your return result of `scanf` would lead you to conclude it actually *failed* to scan anything past the error introduced by the unexpected `-`. Since you know what the problem is now (a `-` where your format string expects a `+`, think about ways to solve *that*. Finally, warning: you're in for a surprise later on, when an implicit `1` coefficient (ex: `2x^2+x-3=0` really muddies up the waters.

Comment: Drop scanf. It is not good for this. Use fgets and then pass the input using your own code.

Comment: @4386427
our lecturer gave us this code as a hint, so i used scanf)

`#include <cstdio>
 
int main() {
 int a, b;
 printf("Reading format: ax+b\n");
 scanf("%dx+%d", &a, &b);
 printf("Read values: a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
 return 0;
}`

Comment: In that case, your lecturer needs some lectures in c. The code will fail in many cases and have potential UB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used 2 chars for the input of the sign, and then I removed them from the last printf
    float a,b,c;
    char op1,op2;

```
scanf("%fx^2%c%fx%c%f=0", &a,&op1,&b,&op2, &c);
if(op1 == '-')
{
    b *= -1;
    // fix formating for last printf
    op1 = '\b';
}
if(op2 == '-')
{
    c *= -1;
    // fix formating for last printf
    op2 = '\b';
}
printf("a = %f\nb = %f\nc = %f\n",a,b,c);

// if op1 or op2 are '-' it won't be printed
printf("%fx^2%c%fx%c%f=0\n", a,op1,b,op2,c);
```

Comment: Please check the value returned by scanf.

Comment: `op2 = '\b';` you want delete 'x'.

Comment: The return value is 5, like it should:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: Look, it does need extra modification to be prefect, i wrote in only 2 minutes, so it has problems... but I have provided a solution to your minues problem

Comment: For some inputs the return value is 5. For other inputs it isn't. The point is that your must check the value and react accordingly. Anyway - scanf is bad for this task

Comment: @Efi Thank you, this really helps me)

Answer (score 0):

Let's quote the documentation of [`scanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) about the `%f` specifier:

> A series of decimal digits, optionally containing a decimal point, optionally preceeded by a sign (+ or -) and optionally followed by the e or E character and a decimal integer (or some of the other sequences supported by strtod).

Hence, the specifier `%f` takes care of the sign and there is no need to read it. Please try:

```
if(scanf("%fx^2%fx%f=0", &a,&b, &c)!=3){
   fprintf(stderr," unable to read input\n");exit(1);
}
```

It will not solve the following cases:

- x+3=0
- 3x^2+x=0